# Palindrome testing function with only the string as input

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a recursive function in C++ to check if a string is a palindrome or not. (A palindrome is a string that's spelled the same way forward and backward like "radar")

The function must be boolean and only take the string as input.

But it is only working for strings with two letters. Anything more than that and it always returns 1.

Here is the code:

```cpp
bool testPalindrome (string x) {
  static int y = 1;
  static int z = x.size();
  if ((z - y == 1 || z - y == 2) && x[x.size() - z] == x[x.size() - y]) {
    return true;
  } else if (x[x.size() - z] == x[x.size() - y]) {
    --z;
    ++y;
    testPalindrome(x);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if, instead of using names like `x` or `y` you'd name your variables accordingly - it's really hard to read right now.

Comment: You aren't returning anything if the process flow goes to the middle one.

Comment: When you do your recursive call `testPalindrome(x)`, what happens with the value it returns?

Comment: At the very least `testPalindrome(x);` should be `return testPalindrome(x);`. How are you going to get a return value when you don't use `return`?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but without recursion, the method in question can be way simpler with a for-loop. Such as: http://cpp.sh/9ezns

Comment: `static`? Huh? Why? Your function will only work once, Don't do that.

Comment: Cheat like hell. Have `bool testPalindrome (string x)` call another function that does the recursion and takes iterators that mark the begin and end of the region that needs processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using recursion, one key thing to note is you have to return the output produced by the recursive function. In this case, you need a return statement in the second if.

Here is the working code:

```
bool testPalindrome (string x){
static int y = 1;
static int z = x.length();
    if( (z-y == 1||z-y == 2) && x[x.length() - z] == x[x.length() - y]){
        return true;
    }
    else if(x[x.length() - z] == x[x.length() - y]){
        --z;
        ++y;
        return testPalindrome(x);
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As for your (now deleted) first issue, `sizeof( char )` is always `1`, `std::string` is equivalent to `std::basic_string< char >`, and `std::basic_string` is unaware of any kind of multibyte encoding. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more C++ idomatic solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool testPalindrome(string inString)
{
    if (inString.size() < 2)
        return true;
    else if (inString.front() != inString.back())
        return false;
    else
        return (testPalindrome(inString.substr(1, inString.size() - 2)));
}

int main()
{
    cout << testPalindrome("racecar") << endl;
    cout << testPalindrome("race") << endl;
}
```

If you used string_view for your input parameter, it would be a little more efficient.